# Issues using OleDbConnection to export an image in an excel document in c#

Tags: c#, image, excel, export, oledbcommand

I want to export an image to an excel document in c#

The image the following formats: 
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage

These are the connection details:

```
private const string OleDbConnection = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
private const string OleDbInsert = "INSERT INTO [Report] ([Time], [Elapsed], [Description], [Picture]) values( @timestamp, @elapsed, @description, @pic);";
private const string OleDbCreate = "CREATE TABLE [Report] ([Time] varchar(255), [Elapsed] varchar(255), [Description] varchar(255), [pic] blob);";
```

I am using the following code to write the image in excel:

```
foreach (var e in Entries)
{

using(var command = new OleDbCommand { Connection = connection, CommandText = OleDbInsert })
{

    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@component", OleDbType.BSTR) { Value = e.val1 });
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@result", OleDbType.BSTR) { Value = e.val2 });
    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@description", OleDbType.BSTR) { Value = e.val3});

    if (e.EncodedScreenshot != string.Empty)
                        {
                            byte[] imageContent = imageToByteArray(ImageWpfToGDI(e.Picture));
                            OleDbParameter ph = new OleDbParameter("@pic", OleDbType.Binary) { Value = imageContent}; 
                            ph.Size = imageContent.Length;
                            command.Parameters.Add(ph);
                        }
}
```

These are the methods I am using:

```
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }

    private System.Drawing.Image ImageWpfToGDI(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage image)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        var encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(image as System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource));
        encoder.Save(ms);
        ms.Flush();
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
```

All the data exports to the Excel file except the image (and there definitely exists an image). Could you please give me some advice on how to fix this? I have been searching online alot but I still cannot find a solution.

I made some modifications according to this link: [Insert and retrieve Image in Access 2007 DB from C# App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211367/insert-and-retrieve-image-in-access-2007-db-from-c-sharp-app). I believe my error is because of the image datatypes. What datatype should I use for the image in the DB and OleDbParameter?

Could someone help me out please? I would be grateful with any response.

Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone stumbles across the same problem..

I could not find a way to export images to an excel file using OleDbParameter. If anyone knows how to do this then please correct me.

Instead I used this approach: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-insert-picture-excel.htm
With this help: [How to insert a picture in to Excel from C# app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716873/how-to-insert-a-picture-in-to-excel-from-c-sharp-app)
And it works perfectly well.